# get value with data attribute and display on other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show the value "1,000 below" found inside the button on this div using jquery

```
<div class="showvaluehere">here</div>

<button class="button" data-filter=".1000">1,000 below</button>
```

I got this so far but not working, it shows the class ".1000"

```
var syo = $this.attr('data-filter');
$(this).parent().find('.showvaluehere').html(syo);
```

for clarity, I want the value of the button to be on the

so that it shows like this;

```
<div class="showvaluehere">1,000 below</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You refer to a lot of elements that are not in the source code you've posted. Please post the actual, complete code.

Comment: If you have the data-filter as ".1000", why would the value be "1,000"? What if it was .2000? .10000?

Comment: I just edited my question, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting value of data-filter attribute, which is .1000

Try this

```
   $('.button').click(function() {
      var syo = $(this).text();
      $('.showvaluehere').html(syo);
    })
```

Comment: this one worked for me, thank you for understanding my confusing question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing as you're referencing a lot of elements and attributes which seem unrelated to the HTML you've shown and the problem you describe.

That said, you can do what you require by simply setting the `text()` of the `.showvaluehere` element to match that of it's neighbouring `button`, like this:

```js
$('.showvaluehere').text(function() {
  return $(this).next('button').text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showvaluehere">here</div>
<button class="button" data-filter=".1000">1,000 below</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.button').click(function() {


  $('.showvaluehere').text($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showvaluehere">here</div>

<button class="button" data-filter=".1000">1,000 below</button>
```